# Show background color in UILabel only as long as the text is

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've set the `backgroundColor` via the attributes tab for the view controller in my Storyboard. But I want to show the background color only in the length of the text which is filled into the label, not in the whole possible length.

I can not attach any image, so here is what I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: Is your `UILabel` in a Storyboard? Or is it added programmatically?

Comment: Does your `UILabel` to keep it's current width and just clip where the background color is shown? Or can the width change without breaking your interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Select the `UILabel` in the Storyboard.
2. Open the "Size Inspector."
3. In the "Label" section, make sure "Explicit" is unchecked.
4. In the list of "Constraints," make sure that no constraint provides a value for the width property. Also, remove any constraints that pin the right edge of the `UILabel` to the `UIImageView` as this will implicitly give Auto Layout a fixed width for the label.
5. Add an "Equal Widths" constraint between the `UILabel` and the `UIImageView`. This can be achieved by control-dragging from the label to the image view in the Storyboard and selecting "Equal Widths" from the menu that appears.
6. Select either the label of the image view. Open the "Size Inspector" again double click on the box that corresponds to the constraint that you just created. In the "Relation" drop down menu, choose "Less Than or Equal".

This will cause the `UILabel` to dynamically change it's width depending on the width of the text drawn inside it. When you set the `backgroundColor` property, it will still fill the label by will only show behind the text. The Equal Widths constraint will make sure that the width of the label never exceeds the width of the image view.

Comment: As you can see in the attached image I dont want to go with the text over the image in the right side. So I had to make a constraint to right and put by "Lines" 0. So if I have a longer text it will make two lines instead of goint over the image right side...

Comment: As I've tried from your solution above, no. I have the same "issue" that the whole label is colored...

Comment: Okay, what if you remove the constraint you mentioned?

Comment: See what happens when I remove the right constraint: http://s16.postimg.org/gzsgnch5x/2image.png The tex should stay in the boundrys of the image... edit: when the text in the green label is shorter than the image its perfect. the backgground is then only so long as the text